# Python 3.6 in a docker container won't start, just crashes

Tags: python, linux, docker

I know that that title might be a little confusing, so for clarification: the docker container starts up just fine. Python keeps crashing when I try to open it.

My computer runs on Ubunutu. Here is the output of uname -a:

```
Linux work-laptop 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP 
Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've got a docker container based on the Python:3.6.3 image. I've also tried this with the alpine, jessie, slim, and stretch images, as well as a few other 3.6 versions. All of them have the same problem.

I run the container named 'nb', and attach to an interactive shell:

```
docker-compose run nb sh
```

The container starts up without a problem, but when I try to open up the python shell:

```
python
```

I get a strange error message:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f32546ae700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've checked $PYTHONPATH and $PYTHONHOME, both are unset.

The odd thing is that if I specify to use python 2.7:

```
python2
```

the shell starts up no problem. Also, if I use any of the 3.7 images and open a python 3.7 shell, no issues there. The problem seems to be limited to 3.6

The research I've done on this tells me that it's likely a problem with the environment variables. I've tried manually setting PYTHONHOME to these values (individually)

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/python
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

with no changes to the result. The only difference is that the error message no longer suggests setting PYTHONHOME

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f32546ae700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I thought the problem could be with some command in my dockerfile, so I stripped out everything and just spun up an unfiltered python image. Same problem. I redownloaded, tried other images, no change. I can't imagine that all (or really any) of the official python images can be causing this, so I'm guessing that the problem must be with my host machine, but nothing I can find touches this subject. Any thoughts?

Comment: could you share your dockerfile?

Comment: Are you running an up to date version of docker? I would also suggest running the image without docker-compose to narrow the possible causes for this error. You also mention using a container based on python:3.6. Are you able to execute `docker run --rm python:3.6 python --version`?

Comment: @andolsizied 

`FROM python:3.6.3


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \

 odbc-postgresql


# Make a new directory called nb

RUN mkdir -p \

 /home/var/usr/nb/ 


# Copy the requirements text file to the nb directory

COPY ./requirements.txt /home/var/usr/nb/



# Install the python libraries specified by the requirements file

RUN pip install --upgrade -r /home/var/usr/nb/requirements.txt`

Comment: @EelkevandenBos Yes I am able to run that command successfully. The STDOUT prints Python 3.6.7. I also spun up the nb image with `docker run -it nb /bin/bash`, and once in the shell `python --version` again returns Python 3.6.7

So the problem does appear to be limited to docker-compose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out my issue. I had added a volume mount to the docker-compose file which mounted a local project directory into the container python directory.

```
volumes:
    - ./nb/python3.6:/usr/local/lib/python3.6
```

Thanks to @EelkevandenBos for helping me realize that the problem was limited to docker-compose, and wasn't present when just using docker. The problem was easy to find after that.

I had forgotten I had done this. My goal with the mount was to limit the time spent downloading python libraries, as the image uses a number of fairly large libraries and anytime you make a change to the requirements list, you have to redownload all of the libraries. My thought was that my using a volume, the libraries would be saved and reloaded even when the container was rebuilt, which would result in less time spent downloading. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, please let me know in the comments.